# Tikz Scaling and Positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I cannot scale the first picture. scale=0.6 does not work.
Also I cannot vertically align the picture. I want top of text and top of figure are same. See figures in the following examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=6.0em]{geometry}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd }

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{perpage} %the perpage package
\MakePerPage{footnote} %the perpage package command

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}



 \begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=}


\begin{enumerate}
\item 
Ardışık üç pozitif tamsayının çarpımının hiçbir zaman bir tamsayının birden 
büyük bir kuvvetine eşit olamayacağını gösteriniz.

\item
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{4.5cm}r}
$ABCD$ kirişler dörtgeni ve $|AE|=|AD|$, $|BC|=|BE|$ dir. 
Buna göre, $EF\parallel AB$ olduğunu gösteriniz.

&

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.24698133918770565cm,y=0.24577572964669714cm]
\clip(-0.5,-2.72) rectangle (11.5,3.6);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (0.06,-2.01)-- (4.43,3.26);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (9.33,1.94)-- (4.43,3.26);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (9.33,1.94)-- (11.14,-2.13);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (11.14,-2.13)-- (0.06,-2.01);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (11.14,-2.13)-- (4.43,3.26);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (9.33,1.94)-- (0.06,-2.01);
\draw (-0.38,-2.0) node[anchor=north west] {$A$};
\draw (11.4,-2.00) node[anchor=north west] {$B$};
\draw (9.56,2.14) node[anchor=north west] {$C$};
\draw (3.96,3.48) node[anchor=north west] {$D$};
\draw (6,0.92) node[anchor=north west] {$E$};
\draw (7.90,0.87) node[anchor=north west] {$F$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [white] (0.06,-2.01) circle (2.0pt);
\fill [white] (4.43,3.26) circle (2.0pt);
\fill [white] (9.33,1.94) circle (2.0pt);
\fill [white] (11.14,-2.13) circle (2.0pt);
\fill [white] (6.36,0.67) circle (2.0pt);
\fill [white] (7.67,0.66) circle (2.0pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}


\item
$0<q<200$ ve $\dfrac{59}{80} < \dfrac{p}{q} <\dfrac{45}{61}$ koşullarını sağlayan bir 
$(p,q)$ tamsayı çifti bulunuz ve böyle tek bir $(p,q)$ tamsayı çifti olduğunu gösteriniz.

\item
$7$ arkadaşı olan bir kimse, bir hafta boyunca her akşam $3$ arkadaşını yemeğe çağırır. 
Farklı iki akşam yemeğe çağrılan gruplar birbirlerinden farklı olup; $7$ arkadaştan her biri 
en az bir akşam yemeğe çağrılmaktadır. Bu koşulları sağlayan kaç değişik çağrı programı 
yapılabileceğini bulunuz.

\item
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{7cm}r}

$O$ merkezli çemberin yarıçapı $R$'dir. $A$ merkezli $|AB|$ yarıçaplı çember ile $B$ merkezli 
$|BA|$ yarıçaplı çemberin $D$ kesim noktası alınıyor. $CD$ doğrusu, $O$ merkezli çemberi $E$ 
noktasında kestiğine göre $|ED|$ uzunluğunu $R$ cinsinden hesaplayınız. 

&
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-0.16,-1.88) rectangle (6.4,3.52);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (4.02,0.3) circle (2.16cm);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (4.55,2.4) circle (1.08cm);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (3.47,2.39) circle (1.08cm);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.93,0.87)-- (5.5,1.88);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.93,0.87)-- (1.04,0.62);
\draw (4.04,0.04) node[anchor=north west] {$O$};
\draw (5.74,1.94) node[anchor=north west] {$C$};
\draw (4.78,2.58) node[anchor=north west] {$A$};
\draw (3.1,2.62) node[anchor=north west] {$B$};
\draw (1.56,1.12) node[anchor=north west] {$E$};
\draw (4.10,1.25) node[anchor=south east] {$D$};
\fill [white] (4.02,0.3) circle (2.0pt);
\fill [white] (5.5,1.88) circle (2.0pt);
\fill [white] (4.55,2.4) circle (2.0pt);
\fill [white] (3.47,2.39) circle (2.0pt);
\fill [white] (4.01,1.46) circle (2.0pt);
\fill [white] (1.93,0.87) circle (2.0pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tabular}

\item
$$\sqrt{x - \dfrac{1987}{14}} + \sqrt{x - \dfrac{1988}{13}} + 
\sqrt{x - \dfrac{1989}{12}} = \sqrt{x - \dfrac{14}{1987}} + 
\sqrt{x - \dfrac{13}{1988}} + \sqrt{x - \dfrac{12}{1989}}$$
denkleminin tüm reel çözümlerini bulunuz.

\item
İki kişinin bir keki paylaşmasının her iki tarafı da hoşnut eden ve adil bir yöntemi şudur: Biri 
keki iki parçaya ayırır, diğeri parçalardan birini kendine seçer. Diğer bir deyişle keki $[0,1]$ 
aralığı gibi düşünürsek, birinci kişi $x_1\in [0,1]$ seçer; ikinci kişi ise $x_1$ ve $1-x_1$ 
sayılarından birini seçer. (Burada her iki tarafın da ``keksever'' olduğu varsayıldığından, ikinci 
kişinin $x_1$ ve $1-x_1$ sayılarından daha büyük olanını seçeceği ve dolayısıyla birincinin de 
$x_1 = \dfrac 12$ seçimini yapacağı kolaylıkla görülür.) Üç keksever kişi için benzer bir paylaşma 
yöntemi bulabilir misiniz? 

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make this a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). I tried compiling your code and got an error. If your question is about tikz and scaling, get rid off everything else, so people can see what's going on.

Comment: I don't know why I have compiler error. https://www.sharelatex.com/project/50de0bd4556f697113601a6f this page (The first page after the toc) shows a not-minimum working example. When I separate  the page like the above one, I have compiler errors.

Comment: @user706071 First you have turkish option in the babel which fiddles with the `eşittir` symbol. So you need the `\shorthandoff{=}` to turn that off. Also you don't need to define every color all the time. `ffffff` is white and most of the common names are recognized by `xcolor`. Scriptsize environment doesn't do anything inside the tikz environment so you can remove those. I've fixed your example now try again please.

Comment: See my answer here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107701/aligning-tikz-picture-within-text/107960#107960

Comment: `fill = white` is strange. `\draw [fill=white]` seems to be more natural but ...

Answer (score 1):

Placing the following somewhere in the preamble removes the effect of turkish option of the `babel` package

```
\tikzset{execute at begin picture={\shorthandoff{=}},
         execute at end picture={\shorthandon{=}}
        }
```